# How to deflate dynamic VirtualBox drive if guest uses btrfs?

Tags: virtualbox, btrfs, disk-image

I'm using VirtualBox and guest OS has btrfs filesystem. Standard, known to me method of "deflating" image is:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=./somefile`

So VirtualBox notices zeros and deflates image. However btrfs itself does exactly the same thing. I have already created 1TB zeroed file on 10gb virtual disk with btrfs... So as btrfs doesn't store zeroed blocks I can't force zeroing blocks for VirtualBox.

Second idea was to evoke TRIM. However `fstrim` says that discard operation unsupported despite enabling discard flag in btrfs mount options. What can I do?